# BadMethodCallException Method save does not exist

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying to update a record in the database and am getting "Method save does not exist"  ---- code looks like:

```
$listingsDB  = User::where('id', '=', auth()->id())->get();

  foreach($listingsDB as $numberOfListing){
      $listings = $numberOfListing->numberOfListings;
   }

  $listings = ++$listings;

  $listingsDB->numberOfListings = $listings;
  $listingsDB->save();
```

Any help appreciated.  I can't see what I'm doing wrongs - Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Actually, code should look like this and should work - -did not know about the increments function - so here it is:

```
  $user = auth()->user(); //no need to query to get the current user, we 
                       already have it!
  $user->increment('numberOfListings');
  $user->save();
```